# Create one XML file that joins many others

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to create an XML using some list of XML's.

here is an example list of XML's

### java.xml :

```
<JavaDetails>
   <SomeList> ... </SomeList>
   ....
</JavaDetails>
```

### c.xml

```
<CDetails>
   <SomeList> ... </SomeList>
   ....
</CDetails>
```

I want to create a Programming.xml using the above XML's

it should look like:

```
<programming>
 <Java>
   <JavaDetails>
    <SomeList> ... </SomeList>
    ....
   </JavaDetails>
 </Java>
 <C>
  <CDetails>
    <SomeList> ... </SomeList>
   ....
  </CDetails>
 </C>
</programming>
```

I am currently looking into nokogiri to do the same as Performance is a major factor, What I am not sure is how to create nodes for the output XML. any code help in Ruby using Nokogiri is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. The nokogiri documentation is at http://nokogiri.org There is also a cheat sheet at http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet

Comment: Is your "list of XMLs" a list of filenames for XML files on disk? How are you mapping the name of the file to the tag wrapping its contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new XML file with a specific root, it can be as simple as:

```
doc = Nokogiri.XML("<programming/>")
```

One way to add a child node to that document:

```
java = doc.root.add_child('<Java/>').first
```

To read in another XML file from disk and append it:

```
java_details = Nokogiri.XML( IO.read )
java << java_details.root
```

Thus, if you have an array of filenames and you want to construct wrapping elements from each based on the name:

```
require 'nokogiri'
files = %w[ java.xml c.xml ]
doc   = Nokogiri.XML('<programming/>')

files.each do |filename|
  wrap_name = File.basename(filename,'.*').capitalize
  wrapper   = doc.root.add_child("<#{wrap_name} />").first
  wrapper   << Nokogiri.XML(IO.read(filename)).root
end

puts doc
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the Builder interface of Nokogiri:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.programming do
    files.each do |filename|
      wrap_name = File.basename(filename,'.*').capitalize
      xml.send(wrap_name) do
        xml.parent << Nokogiri.XML(IO.read(filename)).root
      end
    end
  end
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

Answer (score 0):

To install it:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Here's the syntax:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.programming {
    xml.Java {
      xml.JavaDetails {
        xml.SomeList 'List item'
      }
    }
  }
end
```

The result can be retrieved with `to_xml`:

```
builder.to_xml
```

HTH!